# Problem with notation in algebraic topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading the book "Algebraic topology" by Tammo Tom Dieck and I am having a problem with a particular notation. I have attached the screenshot from that particular page. In the last line what is meant by $\text{TOP}_B$. The category of topological space is denoted as TOP, but I don't know what is $\text{TOP}_B$. Can anyone explain?

[image: Book by Dieck]

Comment: It is defined here : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category

Comment: @Idéophage Thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: More generally fibered product over an object $S$ agree with products in the slice category over $S$, this is rather useful and important when dealing with schemes for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an example for a slice category. The objects are all arrows in the category of topological spaces with codomain $B$ and for two arrows $f \colon X \rightarrow B$ and $g \colon Y \rightarrow B$ the class of morphisms $\text{Hom}(f,g)$ in the slice category is given by all arrows $h \colon X \rightarrow Y$ in the category of topological spaces such that $f = g \circ h$.

For example the category of pointed topological spaces can be seen as the category of topological spaces under a point (if you fix a domain). Analogously for the category of $R$-algebras over a given ring $R$.

This means you have probably already seen coslice categories and the category you are asking for is given by a dual notion.

In tom Diecks's book you find a detailed explanation in chapter 2.2 "Further Homotopy Notions", page 32.

Comment: Okay, so I understood what is a slice category, but still, there is one question. In the slice category $\text{TOP}_B$, the objects are arrows (of the original category TOP). So, the product operation in $\text{TOP}_B$ is the product of arrows Of TOP. So, $Z$ should be product of arrows of $TOP$ not the product of objects of $TOP.$ Is it not?

Comment: Well... the arrows have domains and as such come naturally with objects. Pullbacks are also objects together with certain arrows and therefore it fits again. Just depends on how precise one wants to state everything. Usually that is too much notion at some point and therefore we drop some stuff. An $R$- algebra is either just seen as a ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow A$ or as a ring $A$ together with a morphism $R \rightarrow$.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you very much for the help.